# Pivot Control - issue with data binding

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, pivot

I've checked various examples of Pivots and think my implementation should work but it's having an issue.

Here is the XAML:

```
        <controls:Pivot  Title="Results"  ItemsSource="{Binding baskets}"> 
        <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate> 
            <DataTemplate> 
                <Grid x:Name="grid"> 
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding basketName}" /> 
                </Grid> 
            </DataTemplate> 
        </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate> 
        <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate> 
            <DataTemplate> 
                <Grid> 
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"> 
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding basketItems.Count}"/> 
                    </StackPanel> 
                </Grid> 
            </DataTemplate> 
        </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate> 
    </controls:Pivot>
```

and the code-behind:

```
        public ObservableCollection<Basket> baskets = new ObservableCollection<Basket>(); 



    public pivotPage() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 


        //for testing purposes 
        baskets.Add(new Basket()); 
        baskets.Add(new Basket()); 

    }
```

The page renders blank, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no indication in your code that you have set your DataContext. Try the following:

```
public ObservableCollection<Basket> baskets = new ObservableCollection<Basket>(); 

public pivotPage() 
{ 
    InitializeComponent(); 

    this.DataContext = baskets;

    //for testing purposes 
    baskets.Add(new Basket()); 
    baskets.Add(new Basket()); 

}
```

Comment: This won't be correct as the Binding in the xaml references the baskets collection. Either change the Binding to simply {Binding} or the preferable option of setting this.DataContext = this;